# How would I go about converting my 3D maze to a 2D maze?

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna, maze

What I want is sort of like a mini-map.  I've already constructed my algorithms for both the 3d maze and the 2d maze but I would I'm not sure how to convert the 3d one in a 2d equivalent.  [Here's my code my code from gist.github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4760028).

Comment: Why can't you just strip out the Z component?

Comment: because it's rated PG13!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a screenshot of a plane going through the current level the player's at and paint obstructing polygons black and the rest leave white. But first you would need to cut out all intersecting areas from that plane. Not sure you can do it easily enough in-game with XNA.

I bet it's easier to do manually in a 3D editor by removing all but current level and making a huge screenshot, saving it as that level's map, although if you're going to rotate the cube in all directions, you'll need to do that lots of times.

One other approach is to make a mini-copy of entire map divided into 3d matrix of cubes and draw desired 2d array selection.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I guess it would be easier to do in Unity3D rather than XNA.  The problem I have in converting from 3d to 2d is that the size of the mazes are different.  For example, in 3d, a wall doesn't count as a whole block.  Maybe it'd be easier to go from 2d to 3d...